# c++ variables not changing with initial pointer variables

Tags: c++

I don't understand why the output of this code is not `1, 4, 90`. Instead, it is always `1, 4, 83`.

```cpp
int main()
{
    float u = 83;
    vector<float> te = {1, 4, u};
    u = 90;
    cout << te[0] << " " << te[1] << " " << te[2] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I tried adding a pointer, but this did not work:

```cpp
int main()
{
    float u = 83;
    float *x = &u;
    vector<float> te = {1, 4, *x};
    u = 90;
    x = &u;
    cout << te[0] << " " << te[1] << " " << te[2] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A vector of floats is floats not pointers-to-floats.    In your first code [2] gets a copy of the contents of u, in the second it gets a float converted from (*x = contents = value of u), which is still a number not a pointer;.

Comment: `vector<float>` stores a set of *values*, not a set of references to variables that have values.   So `te` is created with three values: `1`, `4`, and `83`, where the `83` is a COPY of the value stored in `u` when the vector is created.  Reassigning `u` does not change the element of `te`.      More generally, C++ uses *value* semantics, but you are expecting *reference* semantics (presumably because that is used by some other programming language you are used to, and making the mistake of assuming C++ works like that language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, when you create the `te` vector with the `u` value, you are creating a vector **containing a copy of the value**.

When `u` is equal to `83`, doing this:

`vector<float> te = {1, 4, u};`

creates a vector which includes a copy of the value `83`. It is equivalent to doing:

`vector<float> te = {1, 4, 83};`.

In your second example, when you use the asterisk on a pointer, **you are dereferencing that pointer**. By dereferencing you are no longer referencing the memory location of `u` -- you are accessing the value it currently holds.

When you dereference `x` in the creation of `te`, the `te` array creates a copy of the value that dereferencing `x` provides. At this point in the code, `x` points to `u` containing `83`. So this:

`vector<float> te = {1, 4, *x};`

is equivalent to this again:

`vector<float> te = {1, 4, 83};`

What you would need to achieve what you want to achieve is a vector of pointers. This would provide you the result you are looking for:

```
int main()
{
    float u = 83;
    float v = 1;
    float w = 4;

    float *x = &u;
    float *y = &v;
    float *z = &w;

    vector<float*> te = {y, z, x};

    u = 90;
    x = &u;

    cout << *te[0] << " " << *te[1] << " " << *te[2] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

By holding a bunch of pointers in your vector, you can update the values that the pointers are pointing to, and then dereference the pointers held in your array. This would provide you with the current values held in the original `u`, `v` or `w` floats.

Comment: Note that if you did this in a function outside of `main()` the vector would be pointing to variables in a stack frame that will be destroyed as soon as you return from that function.  The results could be quite surprising and fun!

Answer (score 1):

In both of your examples, `u` and `te[2]` are *separate* variables in memory. `te[2]` is receiving a *copy* of `u`'s current value when the `vector` is created, and then you are changing the value of `u` afterwards. But changing the value of `u` will not update the value of `te[2]`, and vice versa.

If you want that to happen, you need to make `u` be a pointer/reference to `te[2]` itself, eg:

```
int main()
{
    vector<float> te = {1, 4, 83};
    float &u = te[2]; // u is a reference to te[2]
    u = 90; // this updates te[2] now
    cout << te[0] << " " << te[1] << " " << te[2] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
int main()
{
    vector<float> te = {1, 4, 83};
    float *u = &te[2]; // u is a pointer to te[2]
    *u = 90; // this updates te[2] now
    cout << te[0] << " " << te[1] << " " << te[2] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should add a note that modifying the vector in anyway could leave you with a dangling reference.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox That would be obvious to anyone that actually reads the vector documentation.

Comment: Hu? Reading the documentation gives me the impression that only modifications like adding, removing elements or directly calling `resize`/`reserve` may trigger a reallocation. Simply modifying existing elements should be safe.